# Emulating a Serial Device on OS X

Tags: windows, macos, serial-port, emulation, serial

I have been working with building Microcontroller (mostly Arduino) based devices for the past few months and have been quite surprised by the seeming lack of any form of serial emulation.

I know about [**macosxvirtualserialport**](http://code.google.com/p/macosxvirtualserialport/), but I find that this project does not suit my needs. It does not seem to be recognized by the Arduino (or Processing) IDE.

Lets say I have a processing (based on Java) application that I want to communicate with an Arduino via a USB Serial Connection. How could I debug the serial communication part of my Processing application without having the Arduino plugged in to my computer?

I know that when I plug in the microcontroller it shows up under `/dev/<tty something>`.

Could I just create a directory `/dev/<insert name here>` and have my processing program connect to it while a shell script read and wrote data to that location?

I am trying to write this as general as possible so I can make it widely available on Github.  So, a solution in Windows and Linux is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Does cutecom http://cutecom.sourceforge.net/ meets your expectations? There's also ready build for Mac OS X at http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/CuteCom.shtml

Comment: I do not believe so as I am looking for something to emulate the serial device rather than emulating a serial terminal. I want to basically pretend that there is a usb device connected to my computer when there is not one there. Please correct me if CureCom can do that.

Comment: I've been using  
macosxvirtualserialport to emulate serial port. Are you sure that you're setting baud rate correctly? It should be visible without any problem. CuteCom is just terminal, sorry for misguiding.